# Play Framework/Scala: "return" statement in Action?

Tags: scala, playframework

I know that this is not the Scala way of writing things. I think, in Scala you would use map. But I would like to write it this way, because it is more Java/c++ like.
However writing the following code the Scala compiler complains "method addGroup has return statement; needs result type".
Omitting the return and using an else branch works. But for formating reasons I'd like to use a return, because I don't want to indent the rest of the code which would happen if you use "else {}".

Where to add the result type. And is "Future[Result]" the correct type?

```
def addGroup = Action { implicit request =>
  val optionUser = GetUserFromSession(request)
  if (optionUser == None) {
    return Redirect(routes.ApplicationUser.show(0))
  }
  Redirect(routes.ApplicationUser.show(optionUser.get.id))
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. The body of `Action.apply` is an anonymous function that you're trying to prematurely return from. The problem is, the `return` keyword in Scala returns from the inner-most **named** method, which this most certainly is not. So you'll be trying to return a `Result` where the method requires a `Action[A]`.

The only way this can work is if you split the functions:

```
def addGroup = Action { implicit request =>
  result(request)
}

// Could have a better name, but whatever, you shouldn't do this.
def result(request: Request): Result = {
  val optionUser = GetUserFromSession(request)
  if (optionUser == None) {
    return Redirect(routes.ApplicationUser.show(0))
  }
  Redirect(routes.ApplicationUser.show(optionUser.get.id))
}
```

Using `return` makes code weird and difficult to read, so please don't.

If saving a single indentation is really a concern, what about this?

```
def addGroup = Action { implicit request =>
  val optionUser = GetUserFromSession(request)
  if (optionUser == None) Redirect(routes.ApplicationUser.show(0))
  else Redirect(routes.ApplicationUser.show(optionUser.get.id))
}
```

Personally, I would re-write this using `map` and `getOrElse`:

```
def addGroup = Action { implicit request =>
  GetUserFromSession(request) map { user =>
     Redirect(routes.ApplicationUser.show(user.id))
  } getOrElse {
     Redirect(routes.ApplicationUser.show(0))
  }     
}
```

It removes the need to use `.get` and also prioritizes the positive branch.

Comment: It might be personal taste, but I find that you can reduce the level of braces a lot using return even if it might be unusual in Scala. Never the less, if it is not possible, I have to live with additional indention.

Comment: @bebo Would the `if/else` in my edit be more acceptable?

Comment: Consider my example only as a very simple example. I already used if/else and the .map construct. But the reason I'd like to use the return approach is, if you have, let's say, 5 conditions to test before you begin to render the final html document, you'll get 5 braces and 5 indentions. If you have 5 or more if/else or .map, than you'll have as many indentions as you have conditions. If you use return, the main part of the Action (actually building the content), in my example only the second Redirect, will be not indented and you don't get countless braces around them.